# Divide a canvas into spaces of different width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to divide the canvas in squares/rectangles each one with the different height and width in a way. Something similar to bootstrap metro tiles.

I also found an example for dividing canvas with same width and height.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654766/divide-a-canvas-into-spaces-of-different-width-and-height)

My requirement is for unequal width and height of inner rectangles in canvas.

[Please see the example image for Canvas with different width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgP5T.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Good for you. And your question is? (Also show what you've tried so far.)

Comment: i am not able to calculate the width, height, x and y coordinates.

Comment: How many rectangles do you need?

Comment: Max 9 rectangle per canvas. Columns will be 3 and rows will be 2.

Comment: Any one is having any solutions. Please share. Thanks